# TSC unstable switching to hpet

Tags: kernel, timestamp

Current clocksource is hpet, which simply does not work with the applications I am trying to run and acpi_pm gives the same errors. I need TSC to work. I already disabled intel_pstate and set failover to acpi_pm. What else can I try to make TSC work again?

```
May  4 17:49:18 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal kernel: [    0.083468] TSC deadline timer enabled
May  4 17:49:18 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal kernel: [    0.083475] Performance Events: PEBS fmt1+, 16-deep LBR, SandyBridge events, full-width counters, Intel PMU driver.
May  4 17:49:18 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal kernel: [    0.083778] ... version:                3
May  4 17:49:18 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal kernel: [    0.083838] ... bit width:              48
May  4 17:49:18 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal kernel: [    0.083900] ... generic registers:      4
May  4 17:49:18 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal kernel: [    0.083961] ... value mask:             0000ffffffffffff
May  4 17:49:18 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal kernel: [    0.084023] ... max period:             0000ffffffffffff
May  4 17:49:18 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal kernel: [    0.084086] ... fixed-purpose events:   3
May  4 17:49:18 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal kernel: [    0.084146] ... event mask:             000000070000000f
May  4 17:49:18 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal kernel: [    0.085580] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
May  4 17:49:18 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal kernel: [    0.085642] .... node  #0, CPUs:        #1
May  4 17:49:18 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal kernel: [    0.099367] TSC synchronization [CPU#0 -> CPU#1]:
May  4 17:49:18 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal kernel: [    0.099489] Measured 493618680 cycles TSC warp between CPUs, turning off TSC clock.
May  4 17:49:18 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal kernel: [    0.008000] tsc: Marking TSC unstable due to check_tsc_sync_source failed
```

Answer (score 2):

Your situation looks a bit different than mine, proceed with caution. I am saying that I do not know if it is a good idea for you to force the use of tsc or not. You should try to understand why you got the unstable message in the first place, before attempting to override.

You can force the use of tsc with a command line option in grub.
First, save a copy of your current grub file:

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.original
```

Then use your preferred editor, in sudo mode (I use nano):

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

And modify the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="clocksource=tsc"
```

Save the file and then:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot.

Example, before change (`/var/log/kern.log` excerpt):

```
May  5 07:06:36 test-smy kernel: [   11.222717] Clocksource tsc unstable (delta = 88022463 ns)
May  5 07:06:36 test-smy kernel: [   11.300602] Switched to clocksource pit
May  5 07:06:36 test-smy kernel: [   11.383987] 8139too: 8139too Fast Ethernet driver 0.9.28
```

Example, after change:

```
May  5 07:27:02 test-smy kernel: [   11.672507] Clocksource tsc unstable (delta = 91987678 ns)
May  5 07:27:02 test-smy kernel: [   12.149995] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

And:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
tsc
```

[Reference](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/06/20/eliminate-the-dreaded-clocksource-is-unstable-message-switch-to-tsc-for-a-stable)
By the way, this can not possibly be related to intel_pstate driver enabled or disabled.

Comment: This did not work sadly. I should mention TSC is not in available_clocksource, it is completely disabled and refuses to even be an option. There is something else which prevents TSC from being available.

Comment: What is your processor? add the output from `grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo` to your question (one line of the output will be enough).

Comment: Currently running a complete hardware check. It's a 3930k afaik.

Comment: O.K. that's odd. The issue on my computer is that it is extremely old (I use it for minimum requirements testing for Server edition, which it is even below that). Your processor is very modern and should not suffer from unstable TSC.

Comment: All of the other machines I could check are running tsc just fine, it's just this one not behaving itself. I already tried half a dozen distros and updated the kernels and installed any drivers I could get my hands on. I am starting to think that it is an actual hardware fault.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a hardware fault. On my more modern computer, the only difference I see between yours and mine kern.log files is that mine loads newer processor microcode right where yours complains. I recall getting newer microcode, but do not recall why or how I did it.

Comment: @user2280032, could you finally tell us the “model name” line of `/proc/cpuinfo` as Doug asked you? The “flags” line would be helpful, too.

Comment: Note to those that found this page: please try the classic IT solution "have you tried turning it off and on again?" before you start tweaking GRUB!

Answer (score 0):

tl.dr. "have you tried turning it off and on again?" ;)

--

Thanks @Dough Smythies for insights and instructions!

I have the similar issue in a VM within Proxmox. VM just shuts down right after dmesg complains about clocksource being unstable.  This VM was doing okay with gpu passthrough setup and Ubuntu 22.04 installed for almost a year, but after installing 20.04 (to install a stable version of HTCondor), this starts happening... So I was hesitant on changing the proxmox and vm settings, and changing GRUB seems like the quickest thing to try.

`grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo` is:
`model name : 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-11400 @ 2.60GHz`

```
[  101.133995] clocksource: timekeeping watchdog on CPU0: hpet retried 2 times before success
[  103.453440] clocksource: timekeeping watchdog on CPU5: hpet read-back delay of 10086670ns, attempt 4, marking unstable
[  103.453459] tsc: Marking TSC unstable due to clocksource watchdog
[  103.453512] TSC found unstable after boot, most likely due to broken BIOS. Use 'tsc=unstable'.
[  103.453512] sched_clock: Marking unstable (103581349355, -127782148)<-(103605679503, -152167759)
[  103.453717] clocksource: Override clocksource tsc is unstable and not HRT compatible - cannot switch while in HRT/NOHZ mode
[  103.462461] clocksource: Switched to clocksource hpet
[  106.842934] hrtimer: interrupt took 88385244 ns
```

Per above, clocksource wanted me to [switch to `hpet`](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/the-system-cannot-be-shut-down-prompt-tsc-unstable.83818/), so i just updated grub to below.

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="clocksource=hpet"`

above didn't work, vm still crashes...i then tried [the below combo](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/tsc-found-unstable-after-boot-4175711883/)... still didn't work...

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="clocksource=hpet tsc=unstable trace_clock=local"`

meanwhile, had to start [clearning up journal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130786/can-i-remove-files-in-var-log-journal-and-var-cache-abrt-di-usr) with
`sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=1h`...

At the end, turns out what worked? Rebooting the physical machine/Proxmox!